# Liquid shorthands?

Tags: jekyll, shopify, liquid

Are there any liquid shorthands? For example I'm trying to express this in a more concise way:

```
{% if job.offsite %}}
  {{job.offsite}}
{{% else %}}
  {{ job.url }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this particular example, you could write:

```
{{ job.offsite | default: job.url }}
```

The value provided to the `default` filter will be used if the left side of the expression is `false` or `nil`.